# SSIS or Tableau Prep ! which one should be used?

Tags: ssis, etl, tableau-api, alteryx

We have huge data in different tables, and in Different databases in MS-SQL Server and need visualization in tableau.

Any Suggestions on ETL !

Comment: Alteryx. Tableau Prep cannot be operationalized without Prep Conductor, which adds to the cost significantly. For the same cost, Alteryx is far superior to Tableau Prep. (Tableau in general is still far superior at visualization.) Sorry, I know nothing about SSIS. Oh, and don't forget SiSense... I haven't used it but it looks interesting. PS, avoid Informatica: their licensing is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least SQL Server standard or enterprise edition then you use SSIS without any additional cost.  Packages can be created and run a scheduled basis using SQL agent jobs or SQL Server Integration Services Projects.

Tableau Prep does have some nice add ons which make the GUI nicer and easier to work with.  It also designed to work with Tableau reports as such it does integrate very well with Tableau.

Alteryx is an awesome product of that there is no disagreement it does make it very easy to some really interesting things.  There are some features which make it very appealing to a data science role.  A number of the examples that I have seen they could also be done in SSIS, the interface does make them just so much easier.  Although there are some advanced geospatial functions that would be rather challenging to do in SSIS.

My personal opinion is if want to move data from one data source to another data source, also do some transformations on the data. Then SSIS is worth considering, it is used in a large number of enterprises.  It has a good support base, comes with SQL Server, the packages can be run by SQL server on a regular scheduled basis.  Tableau can extract data from a SQL server database.  If nothing else it is a product that can be used just now whilst reviewing other products to see if they better suit the situation.

Just for clarity I have used SSIS for quite a few projects.  My current consultancy has used both Tableau and Alteryx for other projects.  Which is better?  My answer will no doubt be "it depends".

Answer (score 0):

For really huge data, technically Tableau Prep would be better as it could end with Tableau extracts, which are optimized for Tableau applications.

On the other hand, as @SQLBobScot suggested, if you have SQL Server standard or enterprise edition, you probably have SSIS included without any additional cost so you have to evaluate also the economical side of the problem.